# Download dynamically generated file using Azure Datafactory

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

I am trying to download a file from a URL.

```
https://example.com/report_view.php?reportcode=59281&action=exportcsv&casino=2210&reportby=daily&datetype=1
```

The above URL generates a report.csv file everytime it is hit. The URL when run in a regular browser downloads a file. Nothing loads in the window.

I am trying to download the file using Copy Activity in Azure data factory.

Source: HTTP request >> Delimited Text

Sink: Azure Blob Storage.

But the copy activity is failing to download the file.

How to ensure that the file get's in the blob storage?

Answer (score 0):

I tested in the copy activity and it works for me.

Source Dataset,Http Request:

[image]

Sink Dataset,Azure Blob Storage:

[image]

Result,never set any file name,so it generates random file name:

[image]

Comment: You tried with a static file. My case has a dynamically generated file.

Comment: @AmanKhandelwal So when you test connection with the http request linked service,any exception?

Comment: No. It connects. But that is a ping to base URL i believe

Comment: @AmanKhandelwal Could you simulate a example file for me based on your url?So that i can test your scenario.

Comment: So if you compare this URL(https://example.com/report_view.php?reportcode=59281&action=exportcsv&casino=2210&reportby=daily&datetype=1) with yours, you will find I am not calling a .csv file, my link generates one. I can't share the exact URL as the URL requires IP whitelisting